# Elasticsearch architecture

Tags: elasticsearch, architecture

Is there a way to sync multiple ES clusters with each other? The ES docs discourage from having a cluster spanning multiple data centers. So to avoid that I'd be having distinct ES clusters in each datacenter. I also need to have the same data indexed in each cluster.

One way to achieve that would be to send each document to each cluster. But issuing 'n' write requests seems unnecessary. Additionally, if some write requests fail, the clusters could potentially go out of sync.

Is there a way for a cluster to "subscribe" to changes in another cluster? Or send the writes to a master cluster (whichever one is the closest to the data source) and let it eventually replicate to the other ones?

edit: I've read about tribe nodes. The docs say that it works just for reads and has some limitations. Is that something that would let me do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up custom routing/allocation strategy on datacenter id [1]. This will ensure that one replica of the shard goes into each data center. Example

```
cluster.routing.allocation.awareness.force.dc.values: dc1,dc2
cluster.routing.allocation.awareness.attributes: dc
```

[1] https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/modules-cluster.html